# How to determine if device uses bluetooth classic or BLE?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a bluetooth device and I'm trying to understand why no BT debug app on my iOS device can find it, and yet my Mac and iPhone settings app can discover and connect to it no problem.

The debug apps I'm using on iOS are BT Low Energy scanners and I'm wondering if it's not that kind of device, is there a way to tell from the below debug?

Connecting to it via mac and running `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType` gives:

```
XRS2 2205:
              Address: 84-71-27-05-DB-B8
              Major Type: Miscellaneous
              Minor Type: Unknown
              Services: XRS2 HID, Bluetooth Serial Port, Wireless iAP
              Paired: Yes
              Configured: Yes
              Connected: Yes
              Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (0x5, 0x27B8)
              Bluetooth Core Spec: 3.0
              Firmware Version: 0x0400
              Vendor ID: 0x0483
              Product ID: 0xA026
              Class of Device: 0x00 0x00 0x0000
              AFH: On
              AFH Map: FF43720007FE1CC7F
              RSSI: -51
              Role: Master
              Connection Mode: Sniff Mode
              Interval: 250 ms
              Host Connectable: No
              EDR Supported: Yes
              eSCO Supported: Yes
              SSP Supported: Yes
```

Data sheet: https://www.livestock.tru-test.com/sites/default/files/datasheets/XRS2%20Datasheet_0.pdf#product_data_sheets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bluetooth Low Energy was added to Bluetooth version 4.0. Since your device uses Bluetooth 3.0, it must be a Bluetooth Classic device.